# How to store big int in nest js using typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

some.entity.ts

```
amount:number
```

But when I store a very large data in my postgres it throws error '''integer out of range'''

My question is how can I store **Big Int** as type in psql using typeorm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Define type `bigint` in @Column decorator,

```
@Column({type: 'bigint'})
columnName: string;
```

Note: that based on [TypeOrm documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/entities/column-types) `bigint` is mapped to `string`.

Comment: how about length for integer

Comment: JS also has a `BigInt` type which can be mapped to/from using the `transformer` option. (Note:  `BigInt` in JS is arbitrarily large, not just 8 byte.)

Answer (score 7):

Just add `{ bigNumberStrings: false }` to TypeORM's configuration, such as:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  bigNumberStrings: false,
  ...config.database,
}),
```

Then the bigint will return number type.

Comment: Since OP didn't mention the database technology, this is only supported for mysql/mariadb at this time. https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/connection-options#mysql-mariadb-connection-options

Comment: That is exactly what I need to search for. I am using lib nestjs-typeorm-paginate for pagination but the field "id" (type bigint) is always returns a string. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Great resonse from [@Riajul Islam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5207942/riajul-islam)!

As an addition to his answer, if you want to store `bigint` in `PrimaryGeneratedColumn`, you should you the following:

```js
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn( 'increment', {type: 'bigint'} )
    id: number;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used column transformer:

```
export class ColumnNumberTransformer {
    public to(data: number): number {
        return data;
    }

    public from(data: string): number {
        // output value, you can use Number, parseFloat variations
        // also you can add nullable condition:
        // if (!Boolean(data)) return 0;

        return parseInt(data);
    }
}
```

Then in entity:

```
@Entity('accounts')
export class AccountEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Column({
        type: 'bigint',
        nullable: false,
        transformer: new ColumnNumberTransformer()
    })
    public balance: number;
}
```