# Cannot insert bigint in SQL Server using typeorm (NestJS)

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I want to insert record in SQL Server using typeorm where column has type **bigint**. I have 'Cats' entity with **id** type: **bigint**.

```
import { Column, Entity } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('Cats')
export class CatsEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'bigint', name: 'CatID' })
  public id: string;

  @Column('int', { primary: true, name: 'CatDB' })
  public db: number;

  @Column('varchar', { name: 'Name' })
  public name: string;

  @Column('datetime', { name: 'DDB_LAST_MOD' })
  public ddbLastMod: Date;
}
```

And dto, that I get in controller:

```
export class InsertCatsDto {
  public id: string;

  public db: number;

  public name: string;
}
```

Saving is performed in controller:

```
@Post('/cats')
  public async insertEobResponse(@Body() insertCatsDto: InsertCatsDto): Promise<any> {
    const cats = new CatsEntity();

    cats.id = insertCatsDto.id;
    cats.db = insertCatsDto.db;
    cats.name = insertCatsDto.name;
    cats.ddbLastMod = new Date();

    return this.catsRepository.insert(cats);
  }
```

But when I send request with id as a string via Postman I get the following error:

> ["error": "Error: Validation failed for parameter '0'. Value must be between -9007199254740991 and 9007199254740991, inclusive.  For smaller or bigger numbers, use VarChar type."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sR8R.png)

I'm not sure if I'm just missing something or need to make some transformation of values or if this is a real issue with typeorm.

Comment: Why are you ever calling `id` a string?

Comment: @AaronBertrand when I route entity I was inspired by this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927625/how-to-store-big-int-in-nest-js-using-typeorm and a note about bigInt in https://typeorm.io/#/entities/column-types that's why its a string

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work with bigInt in typeorm you just need to change type in entity from "bigint" to "varchar":

```
import { Column, Entity } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('Cats')
export class CatsEntity {
@Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'CatID' })
public id: string;

@Column('int', { primary: true, name: 'CatDB' })
public db: number;

@Column('varchar', { name: 'Name' })
public name: string;

@Column('datetime', { name: 'DDB_LAST_MOD' })
public ddbLastMod: Date;
}
```